# JavaScript string replacement problem

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some string replacement on text I'm getting back from a JSON web service, the string may look like this:

```
"Hello I am a string.\r\nThis is a second line.\r\n\r\nThis is a bigger space"
```

I want to replace all the `\r\n` with `<br />` tags so that the HTML is formatted, but when I do:

```
var string = result.replace('\r\n','<br />');
```

I only get the first instance replaced, not any other.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a regexp with the global flag set:

```
var string = result.replace(/\r\n/g,'<br />');
```

Comment: That's done it. I forget that you can regex replace in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. That's just how the JavaScript replace function works :)

You can use regular expressions to replace all occurences.

```
var string = result.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br />');
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php) link

Answer (score 0):

While using a regular expression is most *definitely* what you want to use in this case, you may find yourself at least once or twice more arriving at this problem sometime in your life, and there's a slim chance you'll want to do a bit less than what a regular expression would naturally do. For this reason, I'll demonstrate an alternative method that, while accomplishing the same thing, leaves a bit more room for potential customization:

```
<script>
while (result.indexOf('\r\n') != -1)
 {
result = result.replace('\r\n', '<br />');
 }
string = result;
</script>
```

I like to use this method (a `while` block) and prototyping to modify the native **replace()** method attached to String objects in JavaScript.